# Do I actually have to pay my daughter minimum wage for helping around the house?

Tags: united-states, children, family

I blogged about my discussion to [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4757/is-it-a-good-idea-to-teach-children-that-work-is-linearly-related-to-income).

When I mentioned that I paid my almost-six-year-old daughter $2 for a job that took an hour I had a commenter say that I paid her "below minimum."  (The commenter smells like a troll but it still has me a bit worried.)

I'm almost positive that this is a mis-application of minimum wage law because (a) it's not a business, it's normal family activities; (b) she's not my employee but my daughter; (c) I'm not her employer but her father.

Does anyone know the basis of why I shouldn't be compelled to pay my daughter minimum wage for work that's more or less normal family upkeep work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

mbhunter,

Here's the portal for US Dept of Labor child employment laws:

http://www.dol.gov/dol/topic/youthlabor/employmentparents.htm

Note the first two paras:

> "The Fair Labor Standards Act's (FLSA)
>   minimum age requirements do not apply
>   to minors employed by their parents,
>   or by a person acting as their
>   guardian. An exception to this occurs
>   in mining, manufacturing and
>   occupations where the minimum age
>   requirement of 18 years old applies.
>
> State laws often follow the same
>   pattern as the Fair Labor Standards
>   Act with regard to minors working for
>   their parents. Consult your state
>   department of labor for specific
>   guidance."

So it looks like there is no legal compulsion; unless you are having your daughter bore engine cylinders or set explosives at the backyard silver mine.

Comment: She's a min'r ya know!

Comment: I'd not imagine the government wanting to get involved when a neighbor pays my 12 year old to baby sit. The going rate isn't quite minimum wage.

Comment: "Occupations such as babysitting are not subject to the minimum wage law." source: http://www.dol.gov/dol/topic/youthlabor/wages.htm